# Symfony/messenger - AMQP - How to set content_type: application/json?

Tags: symfony, amqp

I'm using the Messenger component of Symfony to send AMQP messages. 
But I don't know how to modify the property "content_type" of the message. By default is set to "text/plain", but I would like "application/json".

I tried to create an Envelope and a MiddleWare but I can't modify the "content_type" property of the AMQP message.

Is it possible to do that with the Messenger component of Symfony ?

Thanks,

Guilhem

Comment: Are you using RabbitMQ or something?

Comment: I'm using, https://www.cloudamqp.com/

Comment: Looks like you can `$msg = new AMQPMessage($msg_body, array('content_type' => 'text/plain', 'delivery_mode' => 2));`. https://www.cloudamqp.com/docs/php.html

Answer (score 0):

The response you receive will depend on the content-type your service is set to return. Perhaps a parameter in your request would indicate to the service that text/plain response should be return. It will depend on whether that option is implemented.

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented sending JSON messages over AMQP 0.9.1 using Symfony Messenger (5.1), JMS Serializer, and a RabbitMQ broker.

As I do not use the default Symfony serializer, I implemented my own `SerializerInterface`. In the `public function encode(Envelope $envelope): array` method, I have set the `application/json` content type as a header and it works fine.

```
class MessengerSerializer
implements SerializerInterface
{
    private JmsSerializerInterface $serializer;
        
    public function encode(Envelope $envelope): array
    {
        $message = $envelope->getMessage();
        return [
            'headers' => [
                'Content-Type' => 'application/json'
            ],
            'body' => $this->serializer->serialize($message, 'json')
        ];
    }
}
```

Without setting this header properly, the message was sent as `text/plain`.

Answer (score 0):

We can use stamps to make changes:

```
$bus->dispatch(
    new SmsNotification('Look! I created a message!'),
    [
        new SerializerStamp(['json_encode_options' => JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE]),
        new AmqpStamp(null, \AMQP_NOPARAM, [
            'content_type' => 'application/json',
            'content_encoding' => 'UTF-8',
        ]),
    ],
);
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?